# How to get the IPAddress from HostName in c# windows 8 Metro App?

Tags: c#, windows-8

I'm Migrating Windows Form Class Library to Metro App Class Library. In that there's a code-block which gives the IPAddress from the Host Name, below,

```
IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Address);   
IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];// IPAddress.Parse(address);
IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, Port);
```

eg:

Address : `talk.google.com`

ipAddress : `xx.xxx.xxx.xx`

But I've seen that there is no `IPHostEntry` or `Dns` or `IPAddress` in Metro App System.Net. .

If anybody knows means please tell me the replacement for these in windows 8 metro app.

Comment: Here's a pretty roundabout way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11216625/how-to-resolve-a-hostname-to-an-ip-address-in-metro-winrt

Comment: try Dns.GetHostByName(<server name>);

Comment: I've tried that, It exits from ConnectAsync Method. . .

Comment: #ta.speot.is, I tried from the above link it gives me an exception like this, "A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable host. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80072751)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check [How to resolve a hostname to an IP address in Metro/WinRT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11216625/how-to-resolve-a-hostname-to-an-ip-address-in-metro-winrt) and replace 'http' to https and try.

i.e

```
await clientSocket.ConnectAsync(serverHost, "https");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public async static Task<string> ResolveDNS(string remoteHostName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(remoteHostName))
            return string.Empty;

        string ipAddress = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            IReadOnlyList<EndpointPair> data =
              await DatagramSocket.GetEndpointPairsAsync(new HostName(remoteHostName), "0");

            if (data != null && data.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (EndpointPair item in data)
                {
                    if (item != null && item.RemoteHostName != null &&
                                  item.RemoteHostName.Type == HostNameType.Ipv4)
                    {
                        return item.RemoteHostName.CanonicalName;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ipAddress = ex.Message;
        }

        return ipAddress;
    }
```