# How to use StreamSocketListener and StreamSocket in windows 8 Metro App instead of System.Net.Sockets?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm Trying to Migrate my existing GChat application, which is a Windows Form App to Windows 8 Metro App.

In the windows forms application i used,

```
    System.Net.Sockets.Socket _socket = new new System.Net.Sockets.Socket();
```

for enable connection to "talk.google.com".

In MetroApp only StreamSocket and DatagramSockets are available I replaced the Code as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489832/how-to-get-the-ipaddress-from-hostname-in-c-sharp-windows-8-metro-app).

Now I dont know whether the connection is enabled or not. . .

When it step into the code

```
    Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocket sSocket = new Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocket();

    sSocket.Controls.KeepAlive = true;

    await sSocket.ConnectAsync(hostName,"https");
```

i got the IP address details but the Connection is not alive when it passes the code, it exits.

if anybody know how to handle the socket conection and enable permanant connection in the background in Metro App, please say me!

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with [StreamSocket sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/StreamSocket-Sample-8c573931). This may be helpful.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply! In that exaample it is writing something to the server how to get the reply from the server