# How to disable loading warnings in VS Code when running C# projects?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

When I hit F5 on my .NET project in VS Code, a lot of yellow warning lines show up.

Here's some lines of them:

```
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/6.0.9/Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/6.0.9/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/6.0.9/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/6.0.9/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventSource.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/6.0.9/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/6.0.9/Microsoft.Extensions.Features.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
```

How can I disable it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13528952/does-anybody-know-about-the-output-module-is-optimized-and-the-debugger-option (Alisson Reinaldo Silva's answer).

Answer (score 3):

If *launch.json* file change did not work for you, try adding the following line in your *settings.json* file (~/.config/Code/User/settings.json). It worked for me (ver. 1.83.1).

```
"csharp.debug.logging.moduleLoad": false
```

Answer (score 1):

locate the *launch.json* configuration file in **.vscode** folder and inside

```
... "configurations" :[ {...} ] ...
```

add the following item:

```
"logging": {"moduleLoad": false},
```

you should now have a cleaner debug output.